# How do I install the Kotest plugin for intellij from a github repository?

Tags: intellij-plugin, kotest

I have this repo but don't know how to actually use it.
Only did a git clone but what is next?
https://github.com/kotest/kotest-intellij-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I managed to install it ! Steps are:

(On command line)

1) git clone the repo by running this `git clone https://github.com/kotest/kotest-intellij-plugin.git`.

2) Change directory to be inside the repo main folder and run `gradle build`.

(On IntelliJ IDEA)

3) Go to Prefrences->plugins and click on the little cog symbol at the top. Choose "Install plugin from disk"

4) Then choose the zip file created under \build\distributions folder.
Once you click ok it will install it and you will have to restart your IDEA.

One more thing that I am not sure is needed: I included this part in my pom.xml. (the version might be different for you).

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.kotest</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotest-runner-console</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Currently, this plugin is in a beta stage. When it gets public, it will be installable via Jetbrains Plugin Marketplace. Remember this when using the plugin!

Answer (score 2):

FYI: version 1.0.0 of the plugin was released a few days ago, so now it can be installed through the IntelliJ plugin marketplace.

Don't forget to add the "kotest-runner-console-jvm" dependency to your project.

Comment: Yes!! I’ve tried and it’s great. Thank you for reminding me to update in here too.

Comment: Also FYI, the plugin is only compatible with 4.1+

Comment: When you upgrade to Kotest 4.2.3 or newer, you no longer need the console dependency (it doesn't exist anymore).

Answer (score 0):

@Dawn answer works well instead of builing from the source code you can also directly download the plugin from [jetbrains plugin repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14080-kotest/versions) and install it as per the instruction given in @Dawn answer.